# As in the image, from the Timesheet notes, I need to provide an output as in Days worked column. Can someone please help me

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to provide an output with name of days worked, from the dates given in Timesheet Notes column. The column is a software generated column, and hence the format cannot be altered. How do I get this output with some excel Formula without using Macros.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried formatting? Custom “dddd” ?

Comment: What's the format of you've range across months?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, I tried that, but there are times when the date could be 

05-06-07/8/2021. 

In that case, there needs to be three days, so it has to be a bit more robust.

Comment: You should explain how is the calculation made, because neither 3rd or 4th of July where Tuesday or Thursday... Is column N software generated too?

Comment: "but there are times when the date could be 05-06-07/8/2021" - please include all possible formats in your question, otherwise it's impossible to give you the correct formula. Formulas are very specific, often not possible to generalize them.

Comment: How does it appear if it crosses months?  e.g. Tue 29th Jun '21 - Thu 01 Jul '21.  Could you also give us better & complete examples - I misread the example and looked at Tue - Thu being three days, but your notes say 03-04 which is two days.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns The column N is just the example of what kind of output I need to have. Column F is software generated and I am trying to figure out a formula for column N.

Comment: @MátéJuhász That is the problem, is there any way to have a generalized  solution, Because there could be dates such as "04-05-06-07/08/2021" as well. in that case, the output should be " Wednesday - Thursday - Friday - Saturday"

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The output I require is simply the name of days for the included dates. 
So, when you say  Tue 29th Jun '21 - Thu 01 Jul '21, output should be like 
" Tuesday - Wednesday - Thursday "

Comment: So would the timesheet notes for dates that span more than a month appear as `29-01/07/21` or `29/06-01/07/21` or `29/06/21-01/07/21`?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Whenever there would be  time span, every single date would be mentioned.  And for any given cell, the dates would be in the same month only. The example you mentioned won't be the case for me.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),TEXT(A2,"dddd"),TEXTJOIN(" - ",TRUE,TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",MID(A2,FIND("/",A2),LEN(A2))&"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),"dddd")))`

[image]

Edit:  made formula slightly shorter & added explanation.

- Extract the month and year from the end of the text string:
  `MID(A2,FIND("/",A2),LEN(A2))`
  This will return something like `/07/21`
- Replace the `-` in the original string with the month, year and a couple of XML tags:
  `SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-", <previous formula> & "</s><s>")`
  This will return something like `03/07/21</s><s>04/07/21`.
- Add some opening/closing tags to your XML and create a table of individual dates:
  `FILTERXML("<t><s>" & <previous formula> & "</s></t>","//s")`
  This will return each date (as a number) on a separate row - `44380` / `44381`
- Convert each number into the day name:
  `TEXT(<previous formula>,"dddd")`
  This will return on separate rows - `Saturday` / `Sunday`
- Join it all together with a delimiter:
  `TEXTJOIN(" - ",TRUE,<previous formula>)`
- Add a check for the cell containing a single date:
  `IF(ISNUMBER(A2),TEXT(A2,"dddd"),<previous formula>)`

Comment: Hey,
Thank you for taking out time and helping me with this.

However,  is there a way to do it without using the textjoin function. Its not available in my version of Excel

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?  Is `Concat` available?

Comment: This works but will add an extra ` - ` on the end of the text:  `=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),TEXT(A2,"dddd"),CONCAT(TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",MID(A2,FIND("/",A2),LEN(A2))&"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),"dddd") & " - "))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula for one or two days, with more days it'll be even more complex.

`=TEXT(DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,4)),VALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,7),2)),VALUE(LEFT(A2,2))),"dddd")&IF(LEN(A2)>10," - "&TEXT(DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,4)),VALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,7),2)),VALUE(MID(A2,4,2))),"dddd"),"")`

[image]

---

Here is a formula for max 3 days with `LET` function. It's available only in newest versions of Excel 365. You can write more efficient calculations with it, however still it'll be very complicated if you really need to generalize it.

`=LET(year,VALUE(RIGHT(A4,4)),month,VALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(A4,7),2)),day_1,VALUE(LEFT(A4,2)),day_2,IF(LEN(A4)>10,VALUE(MID(A4,4,2)),""),day_3,IF(LEN(A4)>13,VALUE(MID(A4,6,2)),""),TEXT(DATE(year,month,day_1),"dddd")&IF(day_2<>""," - "&TEXT(DATE(year,month,day_2),"dddd"),"")&IF(day_3<>""," - "&TEXT(DATE(year,month,day_3),"dddd"),""))`

[image]